# gcc warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion

Tags: xcode, gcc, macos-big-sur, gcc-warning

gcc 4.9.0 in BigSur 11.16.2 is throwing this " warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion  '20.6.0 " .

There are other errors following this warning, and I fail to compile some of old scripts.

I am looking into solving this warning first. I read many post out of stackoverflow and some of the work arounds like: `brew upgrade gcc` and `xcode-select --install` are not working for me.

(those were used to try to solve a similar warning: " warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion  '14.0.xx " )

other posts to look at: [gcc-forum1](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67734) , [gcc-forum2](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61407)

The other message that follows:

/usr/local/include/fitsio.h:62:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
^
compilation terminated.

My Makefile:

`CC = gcc`

`CFLAGS = -O`

`SPICEDIR = /Users/xxx/cspice`

`INCLUDE = -I$(LHEASOFT)/include -I$(SPICEDIR)/include`

`FITSLIB = -L$(LHEASOFT)/lib -lcfitsio_3.27 $(SPICEDIR)/lib/cspice.a`

`all: moonpos`

`moonpos: moonpos.o`

```
` $(CC) $(CFLAGS) moonpos.o $(FITSLIB) -lm -glibc -o moonpos`
```

`moonpos.o: moonpos.c`

```
` $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) moonpos.c $(INCLUDE)`
```

Comment: The other message that follows: /usr/local/include/fitsio.h:62:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix to the problem.

It seems the problem is related to the gcc version, which was called in Makefile via:
`CC = gcc`

In MacOS.BigSur.11.xx, if one looks into `/usr/local/bin/`
you find many compiler versions that you could try and link to CC.

In my case, it worked when I edited the Makefile, substituting `CC = gcc` by :

`CC = /usr/local/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin20-gcc-11`

but you can try other options, like:

`CC = /usr/local/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin20-gfortran-11`

`CC = /usr/local/bin/gcc-11`

and others.